# Normalizing x-axis to some parameter

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I have the following code

```
Clear["Global`*"]
fp = 5.97;
Δ = 0; 
f1 = fp + Δ;
f2 = fp - Δ;
f4 = 5.38413;
ωp = 2 π*fp;
ω1 = 2 π*f1;
ω2 = 2 π*f2;
ω4 = 2 π*f4;
ω3 = (ω1 + ω2 - ω4);
a = 10; 
NN = 200*a;
LL = 1200*10^-3;
I0 = 0.1;
I1 = 0.48*I0;
I2 = 0.48*I0;
zchar = 50;
Cj = 39*10^-6;
CC0 = 480*10^-6;


k1 = Sqrt[1 - Cj LL ω1^2]/(a*Sqrt[CC0 LL] ω1);
k2 = Sqrt[1 - Cj LL ω2^2]/(a*Sqrt[CC0 LL] ω2);
k3 = Sqrt[1 - Cj LL ω3^2]/(a*Sqrt[CC0 LL] ω3);
k4 = Sqrt[1 - Cj LL ω4^2]/(a*Sqrt[CC0 LL] ω4);

κ1 = -(k1/(8 I0^2*LL^2*(1 - LL*Cj*ω1^2))); 
κ2 = -(k2/(8 I0^2*LL^2*(1 - LL*Cj*ω2^2)));
κ3 = -(k3/(8 I0^2*LL^2*(1 - LL*Cj*ω3^2)));
κ4 = -(k4/(8 I0^2*LL^2*(1 - LL*Cj*ω4^2)));
α11 = -(k1/(16*I0^2*LL^2*(1 - LL*Cj*ω1^2)));
α12 = -(k1/(8*I0^2*LL^2*(1 - LL*Cj*ω1^2)));
α13 = -(k1/(8*I0^2*LL^2*(1 - LL*Cj*ω1^2)));
α14 = -(k1/(8*I0^2*LL^2*(1 - LL*Cj*ω1^2)));
α21 = -(k2/(8*I0^2*LL^2*(1 - LL*Cj*ω2^2)));
α22 = -(k2/(16*I0^2*LL^2*(1 - LL*Cj*ω2^2)));
α23 = -(k2/(8*I0^2*LL^2*(1 - LL*Cj*ω2^2)));
α24 = -(k2/(8*I0^2*LL^2*(1 - LL*Cj*ω2^2)));
α31 = -(k3/(8*I0^2*LL^2*(1 - LL*Cj*ω3^2)));
α32 = -(k3/(8*I0^2*LL^2*(1 - LL*Cj*ω3^2)));
α33 = -(k3/(16*I0^2*LL^2*(1 - LL*Cj*ω3^2)));
α34 = -(k3/(8*I0^2*LL^2*(1 - LL*Cj*ω3^2)));
α41 = -(k4/(8*I0^2*LL^2*(1 - LL*Cj*ω4^2)));
α42 = -(k4/(8*I0^2*LL^2*(1 - LL*Cj*ω4^2)));
α43 = -(k4/(8*I0^2*LL^2*(1 - LL*Cj*ω4^2)));
α44 = -(k4/(16*I0^2*LL^2*(1 - LL*Cj*ω4^2)));

A10 = (I1*zchar)/(ω1*Sqrt[2]);
A20 = (I2*zchar)/(ω2*Sqrt[2]);

α1 = α11*Abs[A10]^2 + α12*Abs[A20]^2;
α2 = α21*Abs[A10]^2 + α22*Abs[A20]^2;
α3 = α31*Abs[A10]^2 + α32*Abs[A20]^2;
α4 = α41*Abs[A10]^2 + α42*Abs[A20]^2;

ΔkL = (k1 + k2) - k3 - k4;

system[j_] := {A1'[x] == 
I*κ1*Conjugate[A2[x]]*A3[x]*A4[x]*
  E^(-I*ΔkL*x) + 
 I*A1[x]*(α11*Abs[A1[x]]^2 + α12*
     Abs[A2[x]]^2 + α13*Abs[A3[x]]^2 + α14*
     Abs[A4[x]]^2), 
A2'[x] == 
I*κ2*Conjugate[A1[x]]*A3[x]*A4[x]*
  E^(-I*ΔkL*x) + 
 I*A2[x]*(α21*Abs[A1[x]]^2 + α22*
     Abs[A2[x]]^2 + α23*Abs[A3[x]]^2 + α24*
     Abs[A4[x]]^2), 
A3'[x] == 
I*κ3*A1[x]*A2[x]*Conjugate[A4[x]]*
  E^(I*ΔkL*x) + 
 I*A3[x]*(α31*Abs[A1[x]]^2 + α32*
     Abs[A2[x]]^2 + α33*Abs[A3[x]]^2 + α34*
     Abs[A4[x]]^2), 
A4'[x] == 
I*κ4*A1[x]*A2[x]*Conjugate[A3[x]]*
  E^(I*ΔkL*x) + 
 I*A4[x]*(α41*Abs[A1[x]]^2 + α42*
     Abs[A2[x]]^2 + α43*Abs[A3[x]]^2 + α44*
     Abs[A4[x]]^2), A1[0] == A10, A2[0] == A20, 
A3[0] == j*(A10 + A20), A4[0] == 0};

sol[j_] := NDSolve[system[j], {A1, A2, A3, A4}, {x, 0, NN}]

LogLinearPlot[{10*Log10[Abs[(A3[NN]/A3[0]) /. sol[j]]^2], 10*Log10[Abs[(A3[NN]/A3[0]) /. sol[10^-5]]^2] - 1}, {j, 10^-5, 5}, PlotRange -> {Full, All}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle ->{Directive[Black], Directive[Gray, Dashed]}, ImageSize -> Large]

(A10 + A20) // N
```

Upon running, it should generate a plot like the following:
[image]

One can see that under the `system[j_]` and `sol[j_]` function, I am attempting to solve the (four) differential equations (`A1[x]`,`A2[x]`,`A3[x]`,`A4[x]`) numerically. In particular, I've defined my initial condition for `A3[0]` with respect to `j` where `j` is the variable to be plotted on the x-axis. As one can see, I am plotting `j` normalized to `A10+A20` as shown in the condition `A3[0]==j*(A10+A20)`

In particular, the x intersection between the black and the gray-dashed curve should be sensitive to the parameter `I0` (set to `0.1` in this case). However, changing `I0` to any other parameter doesn't change the plot whatsoever (one can check this). I confirmed my suspicion by redefining my initial condition for `A3[0]` as simply `A3[0]==j` (rather than `A3[0]==j*(A10+A20)`) and the intersection between the black and gray curve **indeed changes as `I0` changes**. This seems to suggest that I am normalizing to the wrong parameter (`A10+A20`), but this shouldn't be a problem. Because `A3[0]` represents some wave amplitude and `A10+A20` represents the initial pump amplitudes and it is conventional to normalize the wave with respect to the pump amplitudes.

What is the problem here? Is `I0` some how dependent on the x-axis so that something cancels when I define my `A3[0]` as `A3[0]==j*(A10+A20)`? Any suggestions for normalizing the x-axis?

Thank you.

Comment: It’s the middle of the night and I couldn’t sleep. Forgive me it I missed something. Just reading through the code, it seems the system is homogeneous and changing `I0` just rescales the system.  So `A3[NN]/A3[0]` doesn’t change in value.  Try plotting `A3[x]` for different `I0` to confirm.

Comment: Yes, `A3[NN]` does change as a function of `I0`. However I still need to normalize my x-axis. How do I do it so that it updates my `A3[NN]/A3[0]` value?